# What is the current and voltage rating of a diesel glow plug?

Tags: engine-theory, glowplugs

How much energy is put into a glow plug on average?

How can I get that right balance where they work like they need to but I don't blow it out with too much power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies with the type, but anywhere between 5A to 15A for 12v systems, so 4 plugs can be 60A which is why the cable used is a heavy gauge . The power is then between 60W to 720W.

Comment: Is there away i can cut start time by adding more power so ut heats up instantly?

Comment: They may make ones that have a quicker response time... You could also change the supply voltage but I don't suggest that as some functions of the ecu may well be affected...