# What is the normal operating temperature of a glowplug?

Tags: engine-theory, glowplugs

Once a glow plug is activated how hot does it normally get?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what type of engine, but typically it will get to around 1000C after only a couple of seconds.

Comment: @user164191 - See [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/47880/what-is-the-current-and-voltage-rating-of-a-diesel-glow-plug)